# Syntax for connecting to mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How is it possible to call multiple functions on the `mongoose` variable? Shouldn't `moogoose` be called repeatedly and invoked on appropriately?

## Working Code:

```
//Import
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//initialize a variable called app to express
const app = express();
// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

## What I thought it should be:

```
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(db)
mongoose.then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
mongoose.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to mongoose returns a promise (the `connect()` function). You need to wait for this to resolve before you can proceed. That's the reason why you chain `.then` on the `connect()` function and not on the mongoose variable since the mongoose variable itself is not a promise. The bottom piece of code doesn't wait for the connection to occur at all and doesn't call `.then` on a promise.

If you are confused on what the `.then` and `.catch` functions do exactly read more about promises here: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Promise chaining (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)

Comment: Thanks etarhan, I will make sure to check promise chaining out